# Edited navbar not showing in view from laravel and vue project

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a new Laravel project with `laravel new projectname`. so it comes with few options and the setting I chose was `jetstream`, `inertia`, `api, dark, ssr`. However, when I edit the navbar part in `app.blade.php` by adding an item on the left side and compiling and running it, my page does not show the changes. I also expect the login and register links to be on the left as well. I also tried adding a carousel, which is working, and navbar (but it's not working). My console is not showing any error or warning.

What i've done.

`composer require laravel/ui`
`php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`
`npm install && npm run dev`
`npm install @vitejs/plugin-vue --save-dev`
`npm install vite-plugin-style-import sass`
`npm install vite-plugin-sass --save-dev`
`npm install sass-loader`
`php artisan optimize:clear`

What i editted -  basically copy form right side into left side

```
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-white bg-white">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                        {{--Added part--}}
                        @guest
                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <!--Regenerated part -->
                        @guest
                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
```

[image: Current view][image: Added navbar codes from bootstrap]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the welcome page you must update welcome.blade.php not app.blade.php because the welcome page is not extended from app.blade.php my default

so when you add your change in app.blade.php, you can see your changes in other pages that are extended from this file, like your login page:
[image]

or you can extend welcome.blade.php from app.blade.php
Now you can use app.blade.php navbar in your welcome page

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    your welcome.blade.php content 
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `laravel new` with `inertia` will give you `tailwind` as well. It have confilcts with bootstrap. So remove this code will make it work

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```